# How do I write a formula to that shows a student's score every time I type the name in an adjacent box or type the subject name?

Tags: excel-formula

How do I create a formula to do what's happening by the right please?

[image]

I tried Search function, Match function too.

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(G4&H3; INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A3:A10&B2:E2&"×"&B3:E10); "×")); 2; )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its working now. I see you added "INDEX" brilliant!

Comment: Help me understand why this wouldn't just be `=INDEX(B3:E10, MATCH(G4,A3:A10,0), MATCH(H3,B2:E2,0) )`?

Comment: @MaxR if that works for you go for it. to every formula problem, there are always multiple solutions

Answer (score 0):

Excel provides built-in two-dimensional lookup functionality with the INDEX() function.  In this case, what you are trying to find is simply `=INDEX(B3:E10, row, col )`.  So all we need is to identify the row number and column number:

- The row would be `MATCH(G4, A3:A10, 0)`
- The column would be `MATCH(H3, B2:E2, 0)`

Thus in cell H4:

`=INDEX(B3:E10, MATCH(G4,A3:A10,0), MATCH(H3,B2:E2,0) )`